# Webpack cannot find module 'electron'

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular, electron

I am trying to develop a little electron angular2 application based on [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/15/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/)

It seems their is some error with the bundling of webpack, because i cant require/import the electron remote in my renderer component.

in my AppComponent I do the following

```
import {remote} from 'electron';
```

My Webpack Config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var webpackTargetElectronRenderer = require('webpack-target-electron-renderer');

var config = {
  debug: true,

  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: {
    'angular2': [
    'rxjs',
    'reflect-metadata',
    'angular2/core',
    'angular2/router',
    'angular2/http'
  ],
  'app': './src/app/renderer/bootstrap'
},

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.ts','.js','.json', '.css', '.html'],
    packageMains: ['webpack', 'browser', 'web', 'browserify', ['jam', 'main'], 'main']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts',
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'angular2', filename: 'angular2.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common',   filename: 'common.js' })
  ]
};

config.target = webpackTargetElectronRenderer(config);
module.exports = config;
```

Webpack throws the following error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/renderer/components/app/app.ts
(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'electron'.
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this error can also happen when one switches back to using an older version of electron (e.g. v0.30.6 for support for serialport-electron) when they were still using `var app = require('app');` etc. instead of `const electron = require('electron');` -- see https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.30.6/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it

```
const electron = require('electron');
const remote = electron.remote;
```

Comment: I doesn't work for me... I get `syntax error near unexpected token (` `var electron = require('./')` ...any idea? (I'm using angular2 with the latest CLI based on webpack)

Comment: This doesn’t work for me. Still getting `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "electron"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target: "electron-renderer"` to the bottom of the `module.exports` object in your webpack config. (mine was created via `ng eject` via the Angular CLI)

Answer (score -2):

Are you new to TypeScript? Did you installed it? You can install it by:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Your solutions is a java script solutions, which is an ok hack if that's what you are looking for, but if you want to use TypeScript, then you should be able to make it work using 'import'.

Do the tutorial in:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

Also, check:
[TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core' while importing Angular2 on TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692503/ts2307-cannot-find-module-angular2-core-while-importing-angular2-on-typescrip)