# ES6 syntax import Electron (require..)

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, electron

To learn the new ES6 syntax, I've been trying to refactor some JS code.

I'm absolutely confused though by the whole import / export methods.

How do I change this `require` statement into ES6?

```
var remote = require('electron').remote
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432695/webpack-cannot-find-module-electron) but:

1. It doesn't work
2. It doesn't really seems to be much ES6-sque

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 21):

It seems **imports are not implemented** in either Node 6 or Chrome 51 so Electron also does not support them, according to this post: https://discuss.atom.io/t/does-electron-support-es6/19366/18

And also the last electron doc doesn't use imports, they use **destructuring** syntax:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
// or
const { remote } = require('electron')
const { BrowserWindow } = remote
```

`http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/`

But you can use babel with the require hook:
http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/

To be auto compile each required modules so you will be able to use imports.
Of course the script given to electron (the one that require babel) is not compiled so you need to make a bootstrap:

```
// bootwithbabel.js
require("babel-register");
require( process.argv.splice(2) );
```

In shell (sh):

```
electron bootwithbabel.js app.es
alias electrones="electron bootwithbabel.js "
electrones coron.es // ^^
```

Then in your app you can then write:

```
import electron from 'electron';
import { remote } from 'electron';
```

You can also import only the remote module:

```
import { remote } from 'electron';
```

But you can only import both in one statement:

```
import electron, { remote } from 'electron'

electron.ipcRenderer.on();
let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
remote.getGlobal(name)
```

[playground](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&code=%2F%2F%20import%20electron%20from%20'electron'%3B%0A%2F%2F%20import%20%7B%20remote%20%7D%20from%20'electron'%3B%0A%0Aimport%20electron%2C%20%7B%20remote%20%7D%20from%20'electron'%3B%0A%0Aelectron.ipcRenderer.on()%3B%0Alet%20win%20%3D%20new%20remote.BrowserWindow(%7Bwidth%3A%20800%2C%20height%3A%20600%7D)%3B%0Aremote.getGlobal(name))

Comment: I forget this link: babel preset for electron https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-electron

Comment: Just guessing this answer is out of date?

Comment: Yes, deprecated. Replaced by @electron/remote.

Answer (score 7):

These days every version of Electron comes with basic typescript support. So if you use a TS or TSX file in your project -then you can use ES Import statements inside that file. Whether you use an ES module or not.

https://www.electronjs.org/blog/typescript

Answer (score 6):

> I'm absolutely confused though by the whole import / export methods.

Mixing different module systems can indeed be confusing.

> 1. It doesn't work

```
const electron = require('electron');
const remote = electron.remote;
```

is exactly the same as what you have

```
var remote = require('electron').remote
```

If yours work, the other will as well. However, I would simply stick with yours.

> 2. It doesn't really seems to be much ES6-sque

Who cares? Node doesn't support ES6 `imports` and `exports` natively and it's not super clear how CommonJS modules should map to ES6 modules. I recommend to stick with `require` if you are only writing for Node anyway.

---

You could *try* to do

```
import electron from 'electron';
const {remote} = electron;
```

Comment: yeah,  I see what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Comment: import is completely incompatible with require since (unlike require) it's not a polyfill. import is the future, but it hasn't reached node / electron yet (except inside the browser). I think the correct answer right now is to move towards import / exports and use babel or whatever to transpile your code.

Comment: @podperson: It's available in Node behind a flag: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @FelixKling just in noodling around it seems that it's not quite all there, even with the flag (which is probably why it's still behind a flag).

Comment: lol, I am so confused by the TS, ES6, CommonJS, NodeJS, and how the different module types blend together in an electron application.