# export/import custom JSX components (ES6 Modules) in Electron 1.5

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron, babeljs

I have an Electron 1.5 application, with some JSX components that I wrote. I want the components in a seperate file (module).

Given that Electron supports Node 7.4 and Chromium 54, I figured I could use ES6 module syntax, with export. But I am getting errors with the export command.

This note indicates that ES6 might have issues in Electron: [ES6 syntax import Electron (require..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374353/es6-syntax-import-electron-require)

```
export class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello Again, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}

export class CountWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Do I require, or import in the main program:

```
import {Welcome} from 'componenets\widgets'
```

I am currently using VSCODE for my IDE, and I have a Babel watch process running that is with the react and es2016 presets running. I tried a es2015 preset, but Electron is not happy with the require syntax that babel uses.

```
  "babel": {
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2016"
    ]
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using babel-presets-es2016-node5

It still complains of:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined(…)
```

It generated this at the end of the Counter.js file, which is where it complains.

```
exports.Welcome = Welcome;
exports.CountWidget = CountWidget;
```

Comment: Try adding babel-preset-es2016-node

Comment: npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-es2016-node
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'babel-preset-es2016-node' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: Looks like I got the name wrong it is suffixed with the node version i.e. babel-preset-es2016-node6

Comment: babel-preset-es2016-node6' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: I did use node5 and reported the results above

Comment: Just add the node preset

Comment: I did add babel-preset-es2016-node5 (and read the update above to the original note), it still gives errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to make a few changes, but Aluan Haddad is basically correct. You cannot use the es2015 preset, you need the es2015-node5 preset. Or I tried both babel-preset-node6 and babel-preset-node7 and they worked for my Electron work.

**Counter.jsx** (output will be in ./jsx/Counter.js

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

export class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello Again, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}

export class CountWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

**Window.js** (which imports)

```
const {ipcRenderer, remote} = require('electron')
const {createStore} = require('redux')
const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
const {Welcome, CountWidget} = require('./jsx/Counter.js')
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", render)
//$.ready(creator);

const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools())
store.subscribe(render)

function welcome() {
    return React.createElement(Welcome, { name: 'Sara' })
}
function widget() {
    var state = store.getState()
    return (
        React.createElement(CountWidget, {
            value: state,
            onIncrement: () => store.dispatch({
                type: 'INCREMENT'
            }),
            onDecrement: () => store.dispatch({
                type: 'DECREMENT'
            })
        }))
}

function render() {
    version()
    ReactDOM.render(welcome(), document.getElementById('root'))
    ReactDOM.render(widget(), document.getElementById('reduxer'))
}

function version() {
    let ver = remote.getGlobal('MAIN').nodeVersion;
    $('#status span').text(ver);
}
```