# TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core' while importing Angular2 on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I have a lil bit of Angular 1 background, I am learning Angular 2.

for starting up with Angular 1, only dependency is to add the angular sources either the `angular.js` or `angular.min.js`,

when trying the same with the Angular 2 via script tag,

```
<script src="angular2.js"></script>
```

I am getting errors like,

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

so I have searched over SE and found, `system.js` and `require.js` must be added loaded before loading `angular2`.

any way I managed to load the both libraries,

I love to compile the TypeScript and serve the `js` file than sending all script to client and compiling/transpiling everything client side.

My IDE is WebStorm and when I try to write a simple component,

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component
class Hello{
    name:string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on TypeScript compiler on `main.ts`, which compiles to `main.js`,

```
Error:(1, 25) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
```

TypeScript compiles everything but not importing from angular.

my simple `index.html` is shown below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>

</head>
<body>

    <script src="system.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**What is causing TypeScript not to import modules from angualr2?** should I configure TypeScript with Angular2?

I am totally new to TypeScript,

Thank you so much for any help

**Update**

the tsc main.ts --watch output:

```
main.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
main.ts(4,7): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
11:43:39 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: Go to the 5 Min quick Start

Comment: @Jai 5 min quickstart use browser based compilation. would love to compile first and load on browser

Comment: then compile using `tsc` is there any probelm with `tsc` ? `[tsc filename.ts --watch]`

Comment: @PardeepJain updated the question with console output

Comment: `Experimental support` may be the problem with tsconfig.json. i have updated my answer with `tsconfig.json` file check it.

Comment: Decorator support is not a problem, but **importing is**. I have configured tsc with `-m amd -t ES5 --experimentalDecorators`

Comment: @Rivadiz go to 5 min quick start and follow steps, there is a command `npm start` which starts everything and tscofig file has all the things to compile it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you are new to ***TypeScript***. I still suggest you to follow *angular.io docs for 5 min startup*. That has specific instruction and quite well explained to get started with it.

[**Angular2 5 min quickstart page @ angular.io**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

What you need to have basically to start:

1. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) with npm package manager.
2. [Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) with compiler.
3. A text editor or any IDE, *VS Code*.
4. Any browser, like *Chrome*.

---

Install node js and it also installs npm *(node package manager)*. Now from here you need to follow these steps to get started:

1. Create a root folder name of your choice like ***ng2Playground***.
2. Now you have to create one more folder inside it which actually holds all the `.ts` files/ Component files, You can name it `app` *name is just as per docs*.
3. Now at the root level you have to put 4 files.
    3.1. tsconfig.json
    3.2  typings.json
    3.3  package.json
    3.4  index.html
4. When you set it up, as we are not finished yet but you can `npm start` when we done loading all the dependencies, run this command to start the compilation and watch the application, while you develop other components.

---

Now what should be there in these files as per point 3.

> #### 3.1 : tsconfig.json:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "target": "es5",
>     "module": "system",
>     "moduleResolution": "node",
>     "sourceMap": true,
>     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
>     "experimentalDecorators": true,
>     "removeComments": false,
>     "noImplicitAny": false
>   },
>   "exclude": [
>     "node_modules",
>     "typings/main",
>     "typings/main.d.ts"
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> #### 3.2 : typings.json
>
> ```
> {
>   "ambientDependencies": {
>     "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> #### 3.3 : package.json
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "ng2-test",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "scripts": {
>     "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
>     "tsc": "tsc",
>     "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
>     "lite": "lite-server",
>     "typings": "typings",
>     "postinstall": "typings install" 
>   },
>   "license": "ISC",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
>     "systemjs": "0.19.22",
>     "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
>     "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
>     "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
>     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
>     "zone.js": "0.5.15"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
>     "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
>     "typescript": "^1.7.5",
>     "typings":"^0.6.8"
>   }
> }
> ```

Going very well, congratulations! Yet we need the most important file `index.html`.

> #### 3.4 : index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
  <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/main')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

---

#### Okay!

We have our basic setup quite well, yet we need to install all the dependencies and devdependencies, which is absolutely required. You need to run `npm install`. This will install all the dependency which we have in the `package.json`.

When package installation finishes you can find one folder named `node_modules` which is having all the files as per dependencies in the `package.json`.

*If any error occurs while `npm install` you just need to update the dev/dependencies.*

So, i am assuming you have all the dependencies installed and just let's start:

Now as per point 2, we have a folder named `app` now we will put our `.ts` files in it.

Create a file named `app.component.ts`, see the naming convention `.component.ts` which denotes that it is a component file. Put this code in it:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // <-- importing Component from core

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', //<----the element defined in the index.html
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>' // <---this is the template to put in the component.
})
export class AppComponent { } // <--- we need to export the class AppComponent.
```

Now create another file named `main.ts`. Why `main.ts`? This is because of `index.html`, we have defined our `Systemjs` module loader, see this in `index.html`

> System.import('app/main')

This the content of `main.ts`:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser' // import bootstrap
import {AppComponent} from './app.component' // import the component we just created

bootstrap(AppComponent); // finally bootstrap it.
```

Now we are done.

#### Yay!!!

Yet we need to run it, for this we have to `cd ng2Playgroud` into it. we need to run this command from command prompt or if you have git bash installed run this:

```
npm start
```

and hit enter. Now it will compile and start the `lite-server` installed as a dependency. If everything goes well then you'll see the template `My First Angular 2 App` rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding "moduleResolution" : "node" to my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  In my case, at least, this was exactly what I needed to get things working with `webpack` and the current RC releases of Angular2.

Comment: This line worked for me: ```"moduleResolution": "node",``` thanks. I am pretty sure when I was troubleshooting last month or so, changing it to "classic" did the trick, but now node does the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

first of all answering the question, **What is causing TypeScript not to import modules from angualr2? should I configure TypeScript with Angular2?** You've imported module loader but not configured it. You don't have to configure TypeScript with Angular2 but the module loader.

Since the accepted answer is outdated(aimed at a beta release of Angular2),

A lot of things changed including the module loader in the current Release Candidate of Angular 2 (RC2), This is what works for me,

The directory structure.

```
.                             # project directory
├── app                       # main app directory
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   └── main.ts
├── bs-config.js             
├── index.html
├── node_modules              # npm package directory
├── package.json
├── styles.css
├── systemjs.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── typings.json
```

The files are.

**app**: App directory where the project files reside. 
**app.component.ts**: App component file
**main.ts**: Entry point and bootstrap
**`bs-config.js`**: Lite Server (a dev server based on browsersync) configuration
**index.html**: Index page of the application
**node_modules**: where the npm packages are installed
**package.json**: npm configuration file
**systemjs.config.js**: SystemJS configuration 
**tsconfig.json**: TypeScript Compiler configuration
**typings.json**: Type definitions

### Contents of each file.

1. **`index.html`** file

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Hello Angular 2</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
       <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

       <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
       <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
       <script>
         System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
       </script>
     </head>

     <!-- 3. Display the application -->
     <body>
       <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. **`package.json`**

   ```
   {
       "name": "hello-angular-2",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "scripts": {
         "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
         "lite": "lite-server",
         "postinstall": "typings install",
         "tsc": "tsc",
         "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
         "typings": "typings"
       },
       "license": "ISC",
       "dependencies": {
         "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
         "systemjs": "0.19.27",
         "core-js": "^2.4.0",
         "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
         "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
         "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
         "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
         "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
       },
       "devDependencies": {
         "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
         "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
         "typescript": "^1.8.10",
         "typings":"^1.0.4"
       }
     }
   ```
3. **`systemjs.config.js`**

   ```
   /**
    * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
    * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
    */
   (function(global) {
     // map tells the System loader where to look for things
     var map = {
       'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
       '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
       'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
       'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
     };
     // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
     var packages = {
       'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
       'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
       'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
     };
     var ngPackageNames = [
       'common',
       'compiler',
       'core',
       'http',
       'platform-browser',
       'platform-browser-dynamic',
       'router',
       'router-deprecated',
       'upgrade',
     ];
     // Individual files (~300 requests):
     function packIndex(pkgName) {
       packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
     }
     // Bundled (~40 requests):
     function packUmd(pkgName) {
       packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
     }
     // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
     var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
     // Add package entries for angular packages
     ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
     var config = {
       map: map,
       packages: packages
     };
     System.config(config);
   })(this);
   ```
4. **`tsconfig.json`**

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "removeComments": false,
       "noImplicitAny": false
     }
   }
   ```
5. **`typings.json`**

   ```
   {
     "globalDependencies": {
       "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
       "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
       "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
     }
   }
   ```
6. **`main.ts`**

   ```
   import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   bootstrap(AppComponent);
   ```
7. **`app.component.ts`**

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: '<h1>Hello World from Angular 2</h1>'
   })
   export class AppComponent { }
   ```

### Installing dependencies

After saving all the above files, run **`npm install`** on a terminal window at the project location, this will install all the dependencies to `node_modules` directory which may take some time depending on your connection speed.

### Running Developement server

After installing all the dependencies, run **`npm start`** on terminal at the project location. This will run the **typescript compiler** and the **lite-server** concurrently, this helps compile/transpile the code and reload the webpage whenever you change the source code.

Now a new browser window might open. If not, point your favorite browser to `**http://127.0.0.1:3000/**` or `http://localhost:3000/`, if everything goes well you will see a page saying,

## Hello World from Angular 2

That is it!.

---

If you don't want the lite-server to open the browser automatically each time you run `npm start`, add the following to your `bs-config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    "open": false
};
```

> code samples from [angular.io](https://angular.io)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I'm learning Angular2 using the official website. I downloaded example code (e.g. from the Plunkr live code for the Developer Guide for Lifecycle Hooks). The files worked. However, when I opened the files in WebStorm, code navigation (e.g. jump to declaration) didn't work (perhaps because the angular core files were not local?). To make everything local, I used your strategy except for main.ts & app.component.ts which I already had. However, you need to change the package.json project name to 'hello-angular-2' to make it legal for newer versions of npm.

Comment: This one worked for me. I used `npm start` ( when I had beed using `gulp` all along)

Answer (score 2):

Use `'@angular/core'` instead `'angular2/core'`

Answer (score 1):

Do this in index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/"></base>
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading....</app>
</body>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true
            });

</script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>    
<script>
    System.import('App');
</script>

</html>
```

try using this your first component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: "Hello"
})
export class App{  
    constructor(){ }    
}

bootstrap(App);
```

your Index.html file has missing alot. like importing main component using system.js. i.e `System.import('App');`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.5.3",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `rx.js`,  is it a requirement too? :o

Comment: no for startup there is no need to use `rxjs` . basicaly we use rxjs for special methods like observable stream in case of `Http`.

Comment: would be helpful if you trim the requirements to a bare minimum just to run a simple `helloworld`, plus the main problem is **TypeScript won't compile.**

Comment: that is just angular.io's quick start plunk that compiles the ts via browser. **hence not solves my Question**. thank you anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104826/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-rivadiz).

Comment: you can compile your ts file into js by running `tsc filename.ts --watch`

Comment: The issue is **Error:(1, 25) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.** if you read/understand the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104827/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-rivadiz).

Answer (score 0):

You should import these files:

```
<!-- ZonesJS and Reflect-metadata -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<!-- SystemJS -->
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- RxJS (observables) -->
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<!-- Main Angular2 bundle -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

And use this configuration for SystemJS:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        format: 'register'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I assume that your TypeScript files are located in a `app` sub folder and the `app/boot.ts` is the one that contains the call to the `bootstrap` function.

Comment: still `Error:(1, 25) TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.`

Comment: This corresponds to an error at compilation with `tsc`. Could you put your `tsconfig.json` file in your question? Do you an exclude something into (somethinf like exclude `node_modules`)? As a matter of fact, compilation relies on *.d.ts files (in your case `node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts`)...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure folder 'node_modules' (click show hidden files) is in the right location (in the project's root, sibling with wwwroot). Also check @angular is showing in the project *Dependencies* folder:

*[proj. name]/Dependencies/npm/@angular...*

I was moving files around as I was integrating the quickstart guide into a new ASP.NET Core project, and the node_modules folder was misplaced.

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You may forgot to run :

```
npm install
```

under your angular-project/