# How to convert Electron files from 'require' to 'import' for use with TypeScript? Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I have followed the official Electron tutorials along with a few others online and created the files associated within my directories. However, the files shown in the tutorials are **JavaScript** rather than **TypeScript** as I am using this within Angular.

Is there any way in which the files I have created can be converted from using `require` to actually `import`ing them?

[**Electron getting started guide**](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app)

I have seen in the past doing things like `import * as component from './...'`, but I'm unsure as to importing multiple components from the same source such as:

> const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

**electronStart.ts** (this is called `main.js` in the tutorial, but there is already a file of this name generated by Angular-CLI)

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
```

**setupEvents.ts**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ChildProcess = require('child_process');
 module.exports = {
    ...
 }
```

**createInstaller.ts**

```
const createWindowsInstaller = require('electron-winstaller').createWindowsInstaller;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236146/how-to-import-electron-in-angular-2-using-angular-cli?rq=1 did you go thru this link

Comment: I did. I just didn't get what was really going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
```

is equivalent to

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
```

whereas

```
const electron = require('electron');
```

is equivalent to

```
import * as electron from 'electron';
```

and

```
const createWindowsInstaller = require('electron-winstaller').createWindowsInstaller;
```

should be possible to rewrite as

```
import { createWindowsInstaller } from 'electron-winstaller';
```

It's confirmed it behaves like this in Angular 6.1 at least, with TypeScript 2.9. With previous TS version there can be some minor issues because they recently improved interop.

Anyway you'll need to setup another build pipeline to compile TS to JS before loading it with Electron.

Answer (score 0):

More of an IDE issue I think.

Make a global search and replace with regexes :

```js
const regex = /const ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) = require\(('.*')\)/

const str = `const lodash = require('lodash');`

console.log(str.replace(regex, `import * as $1 from $2`));
```

*(This one is just an example, you should make other ones, I'm just giving you the way to go)*